# OBJ C Macro by Stringname

Tags: objective-c, macros

I try to get a macro by NSString value:

Example:

```
#define FOO1 NSLocalizedString (@"TEXT",@"COMMENT")
#define FOO2 NSLocalizedString (@"TEXT2",@"COMMENT2")
```

in .m File:

```
NSString *macroName = [NSString stringWithFormat:"FOO%d",1];

label.text = MACROBYNAME(macroName);
```

is there a way to do something like this?

Another approach to solution is a Switch-Case in the macro like this:

```
#define FOOSELECTOR(x) Switch x 
case "FOO1"
NSLocalizedString (@"TEXT",@"COMMENT")
break; 

case "FOO2"
NSLocalizedString (@"TEXT2",@"COMMENT2")
break;
```

or something like that... any Ideas?

Comment: Why? Your aim is to make the code as difficult to maintain as possible?

Comment: You do understand that macros are evaluated before compilation and you cannot mix them with runtime methods freely?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'll bite and make this an answer instead of a comment:

No, it's not possible. There's no way to do what you want to do.

Macros are evaluated during compile time, that's when you hit cmd-b in Xcode. Functions are called during runtime. That's when the program is run, possibly years after compilation.

Furhtermore, why do you want to do it? What's wrong with

```
NSString *localizedString = NSLocalizedString (@"TEXT",@"COMMENT");
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d", localizedString, 1];
```

?